# Adding new Tab Bar on a tabbed page

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do an app like the image below (ForeFlight) but I couldn't find any solution to add new tabbed pages inside a tab page.

[image]

Comment: It is generally a very good news that you try to do something. However, StackOverflow's staff with extra-sensorial gift are not available at the moment, so, please, provide us with what you tried already.

Comment: Please, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before ask a new question. Anyway it seem to be only a segmented control inside a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply make the inner tabs a UIColllectionView. When a cell in the collectionView is selected, you populate the table view with the new data and reload it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround here like you can create a `UIStackView` of `UIButton` and using *AutoLayout* place that *stackView*

Now you can by default make the *First Button* selected by :

1. Changing the `backgroundColor` of the button
2. Changing the `textColor` of the button

Now, you can create a common `@IBAction` for all the buttons and using the `sender` parameter of the button, you can check which `UIButton` was selected like

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {

   if let textOnButton = sender.titleLabel?.text {

      switch textOnButton {

        case "First": 
             // Highlight the First button by changing the backgroundColor and textColor of the button
             // Write logic for first button here

        case "Second": 
             // Highlight the Second button by changing the backgroundColor and textColor of the button
             // Write logic for Second button here

        default:
            break
      }

   }
}
```

Or you can use `UISegmentedControl` in the same way